# Android basic math in textview

Tags: android

I am trying to add two numbers and display them in the textview using this code. The problem here is that it doesn't add the numbers, it just displays the entire string.

```
CharSequence fnum, snum, symbol;
final TextView CalTextBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainTextview);
symbol = "+"; // addition selected
fnum = CalTextBox.getText(); // store number into fnum 
snum = CalTextBox.getText(); //new number will be added in the code and be stored into snum
CalTextBox.setText(""); // delete whats in the text box
CalTextBox.setText(snum + "" + symbol + "" + fnum); // add two numbers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the '+' operator performs concatenation if used on strings (like in this case). To perform a math operation, you have to convert them to numbers first. I think you can use this:

```
// Convert the 2 String to integer values
int first = Integer.valueOf(fnum);
int second = Integer.valueOf(snum);

// Compute the sum
int sum = first + second;

// Create the String you can use to display in the TextView
String textToDisplay = String.valueOf(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

For mathematical operations is best to use int, long or double variable types. Instead of `CharSequence` use for example int.

to get `integer (int)` from `String (text)` use:

```
int fnum, snum, symbol;
int fnum = Integer.parseInt("10"); or
fnum = Integer.parseInt(CalTextBox.getText());
CalTextBox.setText("" + (snum + symbol + fnum));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
snum = "2";
fnum = "3";
symbol = "+";

snum + "" + symbol + "" + fnum  =  "2+3"
```

Instead you should convert String into integer or double and make appropriate controls such as null or empty, or non-numeric then,

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(snum) + Integer.parseInt(fnum);

CalTextBox.setText("" + result);
```

Comment: I'm just curious: is there any difference whether you get the int value by Integer.parseInt or by Integer.valueOf  ?

Comment: parseInt returns primitive int, valueOf returns Integer object